# SQL Server 2016 - Why would I need to specify a root element for my select statement

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

Why would I need to specify a root element in my select statement?

I'm talking about that `ROOT('data')` in code below.

```
// GET api/Product
[HttpGet]
public async Task Get()
{
    await sqlQuery.Sql(
        @"select ProductID, Name, Color, Price, Quantity, JSON_VALUE(Data, '$.MadeIn') as MadeIn, JSON_QUERY(Tags) as Tags 
        from Product
        FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('data')"
     ).Stream(Response.Body, EMPTY_PRODUCTS_ARRAY);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The optional ROOT('array name') gives a name to the array specified by FOR JSON PATH.  ROOT is mutually exclusive with WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER, only 1 may be specified.  The result of the query with ROOT('data') will be something like

```
{ "data": [ { ... } ]}
```

If WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER was specified instead the JSON produced would look like

```
{ "field1": "value", ... }
```